# Bad results Rendering hair with cycles

Tags: rendering, hair

when I render hair in eevee it looks great.
When I render it with cycles it looks terrible
What am I doing wrong? I tried to play with the number of subdivisions and with the total max bounces but it didn't change anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know why I get bad results with cycles when I try to render hair.
What are the parameters that I should change in order to get good render of the hair?

Comment: I fixed it!
I changed all the max bounces parameters to a higher number and it worked!

Comment: You should mention in the question that this is no particle hair but hair cards with transparency.